# How much space is required for Kingdom Hearts Cloud Version?

Tags: nintendo-switch, kingdom-hearts

Even though Kingdom Hearts Cloud needs online access or network, how much space is needed to play on the Switch?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I cleaned up your question a little bit to make it more readable. Please let me know if I misinterpreted anything

Comment: No, you didn't mininterpreted anything, and it's good.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running natively on Switch hardware, the game leverages the player’s internet connection and streams directly to the device. Theoretically, this allows players to jump into a game with no download times and without hardware constraints.

For the storage part:

> These games are available only in the Nintendo eShop and still require a download of the respective game app to your Switch. This will act as a launcher for the game and takes significantly less storage -- approximately 100MB

Source, [CNET](https://www.cnet.com/tech/gaming/switch-cloud-streaming-how-to-play-dying-light-2-control-and-more/).